# Why the actionscript 3.0 snippet below failed to import Button and TextInput?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package
{
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import fl.controls.TextInput;
    public class MinRecord extends Sprite
    {
          private var recordBtn:Button;
          private var stopBtn:Button;
          private var textInput:TextInput;
...
```

When I run it reports:

```
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Button.
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TextInput.
```

Can someone point out what's wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to compile this from Flex builder?

Comment: @Amarghosh ,I'm compiling it from Flash CS5.

Comment: Are you able to compile other projects - are you able to import say `flash.net.URLRequest`? If nothing works, may be your class path settings are wrong. I'm not sure how to fix it on CS5 though

Comment: I don't know what this means and how to deal with it: `a definition for the document class could not be found in the classpath,so one will be automatically generated in the swf file upon export`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the `TextInput` and `Button` components to the library ?

- Drag a TextInput component from the
  Components panel to the Library
  panel.
- Drag a Button component from the
  Components panel to the Library
  panel.

Make sure that there are in your library.

These should be GUI components of Flash CS5.

**Edit:** I see you have not also set a document class or maybe not properly

The document class is the top level class that associates with your FLA when it is published as a SWF. When you click Test Movie or Publish and instance of this class is produced to the object on the highest level in your swf, allowing properties and methods to be accessed.

You want to deselect all objects on the main stage and click on a blank area. Then you will see the Property window with the Document Properties (width ,framerate etc) . You will be looking for the Document class box and inserting the name of your actionscript file. Say you had all your main code in `Main.as` you want to insert `Main` (no .as extenstion)

Comment: Drag a TextInput component from the Components panel to the Library panel. And do the same for the Button.

Comment: The components are part of Flash CS5 as I said and not part of ActionScript 3 main library so you need to add it to the library for you to access it. It is meant to mainly work in Flash IDE.